# Sending multiple objects with node.js, mysql and socket.io

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

I am using node.js, mysql and socket.io and I would like to get a large amount of data from my mysql database. It will be a set of stars with xy location coords. I can get the data line by line as shown with the row var and it logs to the node.js console correctly. I am also able to get standard messages back to the client via the emit line. I can't however send star data to the client, it just returns a blank array if I try and use an array to store the row var each time.

```js
function starUpdate(sessionid){
 var query = "SELECT * FROM stars";
 var conn = mysql.createConnection({
   host     : 'localhost',
   user     : 'dbuser',
   password : 'dbpass',
   database : 'dbname'
 }); 
 //console.log("Running query: " + query);
 conn.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
 if (!err)
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var row = rows[i];
   console.log(row);
  }
 else
  result = 'error';
 });
 conn.end(); 
 console.log("Star data: " + result);
 //server.to(sessionid).emit("starupdate",result);
}
```

When I do an individual output of "row" to the console I get this:

```js
{ star_id: 1,
  star_type: 1,
  star_x: 200,
  star_y: 200,
  star_alpha: 1,
  star_status: 1 }
{ star_id: 2,
  star_type: 2,
  star_x: 200,
  star_y: 250,
  star_alpha: 1,
  star_status: 1 }
{ star_id: 3,
  star_type: 3,
  star_x: 200,
  star_y: 300,
  star_alpha: 1,
  star_status: 1 }
```

How do I setup the result variable and enter the rows into it so my emit line transmits all the data to be processed on the client end?

Comment: emit right after the if else block. Your emitting code is executing before receiving the mysql callback.

Comment: Tested and working! Thanks!

Comment: I am posting this as anwser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

emit right after the if else block. Your emitting code is executing before receiving the mysql callback.

```
conn.query(query, function(err, rows, fields) {
    if (!err)
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            var row = rows[i];
            console.log(row);
        }
    else
        result = 'error';

   //here 
});
```